# Assign a array value into a variable in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to assign a array value into a variable in knockoutjs.
I can iterate over a array by for loop. My code is

```
<!-- ko foreach: {data: friends, as: 'friend'} --> 
<span data-bind="text:friend"></span> 
<!-- /ko -->

<script type="text/javascript">

    var viewModel = {
        firstname: ko.observable("X"),
        lastname: ko.observable("Y"),
        friends: ko.observableArray(["A", "B"]),
        books: ko.observableArray(["Book1", "Book2"]),
    };
    viewModel.fullname = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return this.firstname() + " " + this.lastname();
    }, viewModel);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel); 
</script>
```

But I want book's first element and then iterate over friends. Like

```
<!-- ko {books()[0], as : 'book'} -->
<!-- ko foreach: {data: friends, as: 'friend'} -->

<span data-bind="text:friend"></span>
<span data-bind="text:book"></span>

<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

I know my approach is wrong. But I cann't figure out how can i get first book's element and then iterate through friends.

Comment: can you throw some light on the relationship between books and friends? By what you are trying to achieve, I guess you want to establish some kind of parent child relation between books and friends...

Comment: @gkb This is only an example. I want to use it to another purpose. Only need to know how can I assign the first books element in book and use this variable in friends loop.

Comment: is this what you want - https://jsfiddle.net/mxq63qzm/  ?

Comment: Almost. But I want to use book variable in the loop. And it's not working.

Comment: Make another computed observable that returns an object with the book and friends.

Answer (score 1):

Three ways to do this:

1. Create a custom binding to add stuff to the binding context
2. Create new viewmodels for your friend-book combinations
3. Use the `$parent` or `$root` keyword, *doesn't allow you to define a new variable name*

### 1. Using a custom binding

Based on [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html) example, you could extend the binding context. Note that `foreach` also creates a new binding context, so you'll still have to use `$parent`. You could also extend the standard `foreach` binding to include an extra parameter for extending the binding context (to get rid of `$parent`).

```js
var viewModel = {
  firstname: ko.observable("X"),
  lastname: ko.observable("Y"),
  friends: ko.observableArray(["A", "B"]),
  books: ko.observableArray(["Book1", "Book2"]),
};

ko.bindingHandlers.withProperties = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // Make a modified binding context, with a extra properties, and apply it to descendant elements
        var innerBindingContext = bindingContext.extend(valueAccessor);
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerBindingContext, element);
 
        // Also tell KO *not* to bind the descendants itself, otherwise they will be bound twice
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.withProperties = true;
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: { data: friends, as: 'friend' } -->
<!-- ko withProperties: { book: $parent.books()[0] } -->
<span data-bind="text:friend"></span>
<span data-bind="text:book"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

### 2. Creating new viewmodels

I think this is the "purest" viewmodel - view solution.

```js
var viewModel = {
  firstname: ko.observable("X"),
  lastname: ko.observable("Y"),
  friends: ko.observableArray(["A", "B"]),
  books: ko.observableArray(["Book1", "Book2"]),
};

viewModel.bookFriendCombos = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  var book = viewModel.books()[0];
  return viewModel.friends().map(function(friend) {
      return {
        friend: friend,
        book: book
      };  
  });
});


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: bookFriendCombos -->
<span data-bind="text:friend"></span>
<span data-bind="text:book"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

### 3. Using `$parent`

Probably the easiest to implement and, as long as your view remains simple, I'd prefer this one.

```js
var viewModel = {
  firstname: ko.observable("X"),
  lastname: ko.observable("Y"),
  friends: ko.observableArray(["A", "B"]),
  books: ko.observableArray(["Book1", "Book2"]),
};
viewModel.fullname = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
  return this.firstname() + " " + this.lastname();
}, viewModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: {data: friends, as: 'friend'} -->
<span data-bind="text:friend"></span>
<span data-bind="text:$parent.books()[0]"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```